# I am calling a function in jQuery, using 'enter' event as well 'blur' event is it possible to shorten it?

Tags: jquery

I would like to trigger a function when my user blurs or enters a text box. I wrote this code to implement that:

```
text:function(input,el){
    var textCheck = function(){
        var value = $.trim(el.val());
        if(!value){
             el.addClass('error');
        }else{
             el.removeClass('error');
        }
    }

    $(el).on('blur click keyup', textCheck); //calling the function
    $(el).on('keyup', function(e){ ////calling the function again 
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
             textCheck();
        }
   });
   //instead of calling 2 times, how can i put together as single call?
}
```

Can I shorten the code that binds the events?

Comment: What is the purpose of the second binding? You bind `textCheck` in the first binding to `keyup` as well, unconditionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You can use `.bind()` jQuery method which excepts the map of event handlers:

```
$(el).bind({
    "blur click keyup": textCheck,
    "keyup": function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            textCheck();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) also accepts an event map, and is the preferred method in later versions of jQuery for binding events.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done like this: {but cannot find any purpose of this}

```
text:function(input,el){
    var textCheck = function(e){
        if(e && e.type == "keyup" && e.keyCode == 13)
                        textCheck();
        var value = $.trim(el.val());
        if(!value){
             el.addClass('error');
        }else{
             el.removeClass('error');
        }
    }

    $(el).on('blur click keyup', textCheck); //calling the function

}
```